# How to modify specific cell value mysql table in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I have table

| itemID | storeID | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 103 | LAB | 20 |

I want to add qantity of specific item for example:'103' stored in warehouse 'LAB'.

```
 public void addQuantity(string store, string item, int qty) 
        {
            con.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT qty,warehouse.storeID,item.itemID FROM Item,warehouse,stocker WHERE stocker.storeID=warehouse.storeID AND stocker.itemID=item.itemID AND warehouse.storeID='"+store+"' AND Item.itemID='"+item+"' ";


            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
            {
                using (DataTable tempTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    adapter.Fill(tempTable);
                    if (tempTable.Rows.Count == 0) throw new Exception("No such product");
                    foreach (DataRow r in tempTable.Rows)
                    {
                        int newQty = (int)r["qty"] + qty;
                        if (newQty > 0)
                        {
                            r["qty"] = newQty;
                            qty = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("error");
                        }

                    }
                    using (MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
                    {
                        adapter.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();// there is error
                        adapter.Update(tempTable);
                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        
        }
```

it says:"Dynamic SQL generation is not supported for multiple base tables".

what would you advice me?

Comment: Side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: And *explicit*  `JOIN` syntax would make the query at least easier to read and understand or even write.

Comment: I assume that `itemid` is the/a primary key/key in `item`. Use it to address the row from in `item` you want to change and build an `UPDATE` query that way.

Answer (score 1):

If `qty` is integer column, you may try to:

Increment its current value by some value:

```
using (var updateCommand = new MySqlCommand())
{
    updateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE mytable t SET t.qty = t.qty + @newQty WHERE *...Your WHERE clause...*`"
    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newQty", newQtyValue);`
    // ...
}
```

Or append entire new value:

```
using (var updateCommand = new MySqlCommand())
{
    updateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE mytable t SET t.qty = @newQtyValue WHERE *...Your WHERE clause...*`"
    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newQtyValue", newQtyValue);`
    // ...
}
```

As @sticky bit said, it is preferred to use `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue` instead of string concat/interpolation.

Comment: I want to take the value before any update @Auditive

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...